# swift - extending PieChartView

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code but i'm facing some issues, maybe related to 'open' keyword.

```
class CustomPieChartView: PieChartView
{


    internal override func initialize()
    {
        super.initialize()

        renderer = PieChartRenderer(chart: self, animator: _animator, viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler)
        _xAxis = nil

        self.highlighter = PieHighlighter(chart: self)
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't override a framework''s internal function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialize` is marked `internal` inside `PieChartView`

According to the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) you cannot access `internal` members of frameworks (they must be marked `open`).

> ***Internal access*** enables entities to be used within any source file
>   from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a
>   framework’s internal structure.
>
> ...
>
> ***Open*** class members can be overridden by subclasses within the module
>   where they’re defined, and within any module that imports the module
>   where they’re defined.

The maintainer(s) of [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) may not want that method to be overridden but since it's open source perhaps you/someone can attempt to have that changed if there is a good reason or use case.